# Memory Leakage regarding to the new instance?

Tags: c++

I am confused if there would be memory leakage in the following code.

```
Pose2 wheel_odom_;
while (1)
{
    wheel_odom_ = Pose2(position.x, position.y, position.yaw); // memory leakag??
}
```

I think there will be memory leakage in while loop since the new instance is creating at each time, but I am not sure how it could be figured out without the leakage.

Comment: I'm confused about why this question got four down votes.

Comment: One of the design goals of C++ is to make using objects as simple as using built in types like `int` and `double`. So C++ has been designed so that code like the above can be written **without** having to explicitly deal with memory issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no memory leakage here whatsoever (unless the constructor or the assignment of `Pose` has a bug).

All the objects in your snippet of code have [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) which means that the compiler automatically takes care of allocation/deallocation of storage and destruction of the objects.

Most memory leakage issues on C++ come from explicitly using `new`, which you shouldn't do btw.